# Mockito framework

Tags: java, spring, mockito

I want to test follow method

```
@Service
public class SortingService {

    @Autowired
    private SortingExecutionCore sortingExecutionCore;

    @Autowired
    private TaskService taskService;

public void checkForFullLoading() {
    Integer countOfThreads = sortingExecutionCore.countOfFreeThreads();
    Integer countOfWaitingTasks = taskService.waitingTaskCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < countOfSearchsForWaitingTask; i++) {
            try {
                startForNewSort();
...
```

startForNewSort - SortingService method
SortingExecutionCore and TaskService - spring beans

Its my Test class:

```
 public class SortingServiceTest {

        @InjectMocks
        SortingService sortingService;

        @Mock
        SortingExecutionCore sortingExecutionCore;

        @Mock
        TaskService taskService;

        @Before
        public void initMocks(){
            sortingService = mock(SortingService.class);
            MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        }

        @Test
        public void testCheckForFullLoading() throws Exception {

            when(sortingExecutionCore.countOfFreeThreads()).thenReturn(1);
            when(taskService.waitingTaskCount()).thenReturn(1);

            sortingService.checkForFullLoading();
            verify(sortingService, times(1)).startForNewSort();

        }
```

And when I run test. I already have 
Wanted but not invoked exception

Comment: Why are you verifying a non mock class??

Comment: And why are you mocking the sortingService?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you mocked the class you are trying to test.  Let's examine your test method:

```
@Test
    public void testCheckForFullLoading() throws Exception {

        when(sortingExecutionCore.countOfFreeThreads()).thenReturn(1);
        when(taskService.waitingTaskCount()).thenReturn(1);

        sortingService.checkForFullLoading();  //Stubbed method on mocked class.
        verify(sortingService, times(1)).startForNewSort();

    }
```

Remember that when you mock a class, all method calls become stubs: they are faked out method calls that inherently do nothing, instead returning whatever it is you specify.

So, when `sortingService.checkForFullLoading()` is called, it actually does nothing, because `sortingService` is a mocked object.  This means that `sortingService.startForNewSort()` is consequently never called, and the verify correctly identifies this.

You need to execute your test in a manner that sortingService is not mocked, so that when `checkForFullLoading()` is called, it is executed for real.  `startForNewSort()` should be made private if it's only used within that class (it will not be visible from the test if you do this, so if you want to verify that it was called, you'll need to use mocks of what it interacts with to ensure it was called and functions).  If `startForNewSort()` is called outside of `SortingService`, you may end up having to spy `SortingService` instead of mocking.